# Hook a variable value taken for each tick in Netlogo Headless

Tags: netlogo

I parse the pens in a netlogo script (`workspace.plotManager.plots.map{_.pens.map{_.saveString}`). Often it represents a plot of a given variable in function of ticks. I was wondering if it was possible to hook each ploted value for every tick, so that I can get an Array of each value taken for each tick ?
Thanks